# Multiple mysql query resulting in null return

Tags: php, mysql

While doing a PHP function using two mysql query, the second one returns null, which shouldn't have, since both of them works in phpmyadmin SQL query submition.

Here is the function:

```
  public static function getStates($countryId) {
     try {
       $query    = "SELECT * FROM `Apostas` WHERE `idConfronto` = ".$countryId;
       $result = dbconfig::run($query);
       if(!$result) {
         throw new exception("Confronto invalido.");
       }
       $res = array();
       while($resultSet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $sql2   = "SELECT * FROM `Mercados` WHERE `idMercado` = ".$resultSet["idMercado"];
        $result2 = dbconfig::run($sql2);
        if(!$result2) {
            throw new exception("Não há mercados.");
        }
        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
            $res[$resultSet['idMercado']] = $row2['nomeMercado'];
        }
       }
       $data = array('status'=>'success', 'tp'=>1, 'msg'=>"States fetched successfully.", 'result'=>$res);
     } catch (Exception $e) {
       $data = array('status'=>'error', 'tp'=>0, 'msg'=>$e->getMessage());
     } finally {
        return $data;
     }
   }
```

The first query works everytime, but the second one goes towards the  exception "Não há mercados".

After debugging the function the variable $resultSet["idMercado"] is working and the sql query also works, but the code results in the exception.

What I'm doing wrong? Perhaps something with the syntax?

--EDIT1:
As requested, the code for dbconfig::run:

```
  public static function run($query) {
    try {
      if(empty($query) && !isset($query)) {
        throw new exception("Query string is not set.");
      }
      $result = mysqli_query(self::$con, $query);
      self::close();
     return $result;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    }

  }
```

--EDIT2:
As Cavid suggested, do all querys before closing the connection, here is how the function turned out:

```
public static function getStates($countryId) {
     try {
       $query    = "SELECT * FROM `Apostas` WHERE `idConfronto` = ".$countryId;
       $result = $conn->query($query);
       if(!$result) {
         throw new exception("Confronto invalido.");
       }
       $res = array();
       if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($resultSet = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $sql2   = "SELECT * FROM `Mercados` WHERE `idMercado` = ".$resultSet['idMercado'];
            $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
            if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $res[$resultSet['idMercado']] = $row2['nomeMercado'];
                }
            }
           }
       }
       $data = array('status'=>'success', 'tp'=>1, 'msg'=>"States fetched successfully.", 'result'=>$res);
     } catch (Exception $e) {
       $data = array('status'=>'error', 'tp'=>0, 'msg'=>$e->getMessage());
     } finally {
        return $data;
     }
     $conn->close();
   }
```

Its giving me now a error code 500 "Internal server error"

Comment: Do you have a code chunk from `dbconfig::run`... as it may be something in there that doesnt handle doing multiple queries.

Comment: Just do not throw exception, add empty array if result is null

Comment: Also wrap `$resultSet["idMercado"]` in single quotes in your sql2 query, so if its empty, it doesn't break your SQL.

Comment: why do you close connection after your query ? every time after a query it closes. it should be closed at the end of your page after all queries

Comment: @Randall I've added the chunk as a edit also done the single quote, Cavid I've done it, its just not throwing the exception but its not returning me the data from the query yet, I'll try another mysql connection that closes after all querys.

Comment: @CavidKərimov I've added an edit with your suggestion

Comment: ok, what is the result ?

Comment: Its giving me now a error code 500 "Internal server error"

Comment: there is an error somewhere in your code, enable error_reporting(1) to see it

Comment: just comment //self::close();

Comment: POST http://localhost/api.php?type=getStates&countryId=6 500 (Internal Server Error) its what I'm getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of going in two different tables that has a Reference id in both, i suggest you to JOIN them and only use one while loop:

```
public static function getStates($countryId) {
    try {
        // Inner join both tables
        $query    = "SELECT a.idMercado, a.idConfronto, b.nomeMercado FROM Apostas AS a ";
        $query    .= "INNER JOIN ";
        $query    .= "Mercados AS b ";
        $query    .= "ON a.idMercado = b.idMercado ";
        $query    .= "WHERE a.idConfronto = " . $countryId;
        $result = dbconfig::run($query);
        if(!$result) {
            throw new exception("Confronto invalido.");
        }
        // Results
        $res = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $res[$row['idMercado']] = $row['nomeMercado'];
        }
        $data = array('status'=>'success', 'tp'=>1, 'msg'=>"States fetched successfully.", 'result'=>$res);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $data = array('status'=>'error', 'tp'=>0, 'msg'=>$e->getMessage());
    } finally {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just missing few ';', I've thought of using inner join but my implementation didn't work, I've run your code and it showed me no error, but it didn't show me the results, it might be a javascript problem, if it is, I'll try to fix it and give you the answer tick

Comment: @GuilhermeGarciadaRosa Remove "2" in "while": $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)

Comment: I've done a simple console.log(data); at my javascript function, to see what returned, its giving me a empty array, I've tested the code in phpmyadmin sql and it worked, why is it not returning an array??

Comment: You're right id did missed some ';' my bad hehe, just edited my post.

Comment: Working!! Thank you